# Simple MVC NerdDinners Lambda

Tags: model-view-controller, lambda, nerddinner

In this code from Microsoft's MVC Tutorial NerdDinners:

> public class DinnerRepository {
>
> ```
> private NerdDinnerDataContext db = new NerdDinnerDataContext();
>
> //
> // Query Methods
>
> public IQueryable<Dinner> FindAllDinners() {
>     return db.Dinners;
> }
>
> public IQueryable<Dinner> FindUpcomingDinners() {
>     return from dinner in db.Dinners
>            where dinner.EventDate > DateTime.Now
>            orderby dinner.EventDate
>            select dinner;
> }
>
> public Dinner GetDinner(int id) {
>     return db.Dinners.SingleOrDefault(d => d.DinnerID == id);
> }
>
> //
> // Insert/Delete Methods
>
> public void Add(Dinner dinner) {
>     db.Dinners.InsertOnSubmit(dinner);
> }
>
> public void Delete(Dinner dinner) {
>     db.RSVPs.DeleteAllOnSubmit(dinner.RSVPs);
>     db.Dinners.DeleteOnSubmit(dinner);
> }
>
> //
> // Persistence 
>
> public void Save() {
>     db.SubmitChanges();
> }
> ```
>
> }

What does:

> ```
> public Dinner GetDinner(int id) {
>     return db.Dinners.SingleOrDefault(d => d.DinnerID == id);
> }
> ```

the "d" mean? How does this code work?  I know it it bringing back dinners where dinnerid matches id from the function parameter.  I don't understand the "d goes to..." means.  I know it is a lambda but I don't really get it.  What is the "d" for?  What does it do?

Could this have been written without the lambda here (how)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should probably read up on [anonymous methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k(VS.80).aspx).

Basically the code you are referring to can be written as an anonymous method without lamba syntax like this:

```
public Dinner GetDinner(int id) {    
   return db.Dinners.SingleOrDefault(delegate (Dinner d) {
                                       return d.DinnerID == id;
                                     });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand lambda syntax and what it's used for.

Here's an [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericwhite/pages/Lambda-Expressions.aspx) that does a decent job of explaining it.

However, to shortly answer your question in regards to the NerdDinner context, "d" in this context is just a parameter passed into the lamda expression that is a Dinner object.

Comment: But how did d ever get so that it could refer to db dinners?

Comment: @johnny because one of the SingleOrDefault overloads takes an expression that is basically a Func<T> where T is a Dinner

Comment: The official notation of the => operator is to read it as "goes to", so it's actually correct to say it like that.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Comment: @womp oh ok, didn't know that, will modify my answer.  I still like "such that" myself, but whatever =P

Comment: The article was helpful.  Thank you.  But, how does d become a dinner object?

In the article: ChangeInt myDelegate = x => x * 2; and he says that "This lambda expression is an anonymous method that takes one argument x, and returns x * 2."

In my context d is the argument, but I don't see anything that sends something that makes 'd' a dinner object, like this from the article:

Console.WriteLine("{0}", myDelegate(5));

Here a five is sent and x becomes five.  In mine there's just 'd' and I see no where that "makes" d a dinner object.

Comment: Is it because my return type is Dinner and therefore d is being equated with that type (Dinner)?

Comment: @Johny I believe the return type has more to do with the SingleOrDefault function and less to do with the expression d => d.DinnerID == id.  You can actually use SingleOrDefault without passing anything into it, and it will still return to you a Dinner object, it just won't be filtered as was requested.  With the expression you are able to filter it down to only the Dinner you want.

Comment: @Johny as an example you could do this: (from d in db.Dinners where d.DinnerID == id select d).SingleOrDefault(); and it would return a Dinner object.  Actually with SingleOrDefault it might throw an exception if there's more than one.  A better example would be FirstOrDefault() which would return the first Dinner object it found in the set.

Answer (score 2):

This is similar too...

```
from d in db.Dinners
where d.DinnerID == id
select d
```

The code basically loops around the dinners returning the first Dinner or the default if none is found.

This is a case where the naming conventions used in a sample aren't always appropriate in production.  Using a "d" as a local variable is usually fround upon and choosing a variable name of "dinner" would probably be more appropriate, although in this case the scope of d is so small it is clear either way, as long as you know how lambda expressions work.

Comment: so d here in your example "becomes" db.dinners - the whole object, right?

Comment: No, each Dinner on the list is tested separately by the expression. "The code basically loops around the dinners..."

Answer (score 0):

This bit of code:

```
d => d.DinnerID == id
```

Can be thought of as defining a function of type `Func<Dinner, bool>`.

Whatever you pass it to, this function can be called, and passed `Dinner`, and it will give back a `bool`.

```
void Foo(Func<Dinner, bool> f)
{
    bool result = f(new Dinner());
}
```

In your real example, the function `SingleOrDefault` will call the function you give it multiple times, passing it a different `Dinner` each time, and will return the `Dinner` for which the function returns `true`.

In fact, as you're using `IQueryable`, this is only *conceptually* what happens. The chances are, the code of the function is converted into SQL, and all the execution is done inside the database.